# Set the format for the double

Tags: java, android, double, converters

How to set the output format `lat` and `lng` like this: `0.000000`?

```
  double lat = marker.getPosition().latitude;
  double lng = marker.getPosition().longitude;
```

Preferably without converting to a `String`, so that the output is a `double`.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense-  variables don't have an output format.  If you want to output only the first X digits, the time to do that is when you convert it to a string.

Comment: [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No numbers in Java have any kind of output format associated with them.  To output them at all, they are converted to a `String`, even if you call `System.out.println(marker.getPosition().latitude)`.

It is possible to format a `double`, like any number, but only when converting to a `String`.

You can use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000000");
String formattedLat = df.format(marker.getPosition().latitude);
```

(The `0` is necessary instead of `#` to make trailing zeroes show up.)

It is also possible to use [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

But conversion to a `String` is necessary if you want to format the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method to round to 6 decimal places using [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
double roundDecimals(double d) {
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("0.000000"); 
    return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
}
```

use like:

```
double lat = roundDecimals(marker.getPosition().latitude);
double lng = roundDecimals(marker.getPosition().longitude);
```

The link posted by @TronicZomB has more relevant information and is a good read.